# wordpress install on raspbian (target not a directory)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I'm following the tutorial on raspberrypi.org, [lamp tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress/worksheet/), and have ran into this problem twice now.  The exact spot that I get the problem is in the section titled 'Download Wordpress'. @sudo mv wordpress/*  when I enter this command the terminal returns:  mv target 'wordpress/xmlrpc.php' is not a directory.  When I try to view the file tree the only file listed is index.php.  The second time I ran through the steps I followed the directions very closely, and have the same error holding me up.

I don't have a lot of experience with linux operating systems, and am wondering if I'm missing something because they assume I should know to do something not listed.

Also after my first encounter I started over completely doing fresh install of raspbian, update, upgrade, and installed apache, php and sql because I wasnt sure what was happening behind the scenes.  Do I need to start over again, or can I continue with my LAMP set up from this state? (providing I'm able to get beyond the mv wordpress/*)

Comment: Did you forget the `.` at the end of the line, as was shown in the tutorial?  In Linux, `.` means the current directory, while `..` means one level higher.  That's why they're there whenever you run `ls -a` in a directory.

Comment: Also, in Linux, every command you want to run in the terminal has a manual that can be accessed by `man <command>`, so you can check for additional flags like recursion and force

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance that you are missing the "." dot at the end of the command. Meaning, copy all WordPress files to my current working directory. Given that `/var/www/html` is your target directory to move WordPress files run:

```
# cd /var/www/html
# mv /path/to/wordpress/* .
```

Alternatively simply use an absolute path like:

```
# mv /path/to/wordpress/* /var/www/html/
```